# PowerShell Script not able to determine file paths if launched from c# code

Tags: c#, powershell, filesystems

I am running a PowerShell script using C#. The build is not able to determine the different file path written in the script but if I run script from command line it is working fine.

Here is my code for the running script:

```
 private const string ScriptPath = "F:\\";
 private const string SubPath = "build\\Build.ps1";

 public Collection<PSObject> ExecuteBuildScript(BuildParams buildParams)
        {
            string executablePath = String.Empty;
            string[] subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(ScriptPath);
            Collection<PSObject> psOutput = null;

            //Get path of appropriate branch
            foreach (var subdirectory in subdirectories)
            {
                if (subdirectory.Contains(buildParams.Branch))
                {
                    executablePath = subdirectory;
                    break;
                }
            }


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(executablePath))
            {
                using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    //Enable the powershell execution on the system
                    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                    runspace.Open();
                    RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
                    runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

                    ps.AddScript(Path.Combine(executablePath, SubPath));
                    ps.AddParameter("kit", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildParams.Kit) ? buildParams.Kit : "3CLogic");
                    ps.AddParameter("config", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildParams.Config) ? buildParams.Config : "Release");
                    ps.AddParameter("version", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildParams.ClientVersion) ? buildParams.ClientVersion : "latest");
                    ps.AddParameter("revision", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildParams.ClientRevision) ? buildParams.ClientRevision : "latest");
                    ps.AddParameter("serviceversion", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildParams.ServiceVersion) ? buildParams.ServiceVersion : "latest");
                    psOutput = ps.Invoke();

                    // check the other output streams (for example, the error stream)
                    if (ps.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ps.Streams.Error[0]);
                        // error records were written to the error stream.
                        // do something with the items found.
                    }

                }
            }
            return psOutput;
        }
```

Let say I want to import another script from called script it just failed to get path. Example importing `include.ps1` from `build.ps1` just not working and also `Get-Location` pick location of IIS server location.

```
. build\include.ps1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$MyInvocation` variable to determine the current script directory and combine the path using the `Join-Path` cmdlet:

```
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
. (Join-Path $scriptPath 'build\include.ps1')
```